# Jest how to test nodejs restapi endpoints

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, jestjs

We have a `RESTapi` written in **NodeJS**. Right now we don't have any testing framework setup for this project. So we choose to go with the Jest framework for check our API.

This is the folder strucuture

```
/
/src
  /controllers
  /routes
/app.js
```

What we need to do basically is, we need to check call each and every end point in our API and make sure it's response code is equals to **200**. How do I call all endpoints one by one and find where it's not returns **200**.

I go though some articles and find out `__mocks__` and `__test__` But I no idea how to configure those. I have a route that can be accessible by `localhost:3000/banner` If I run test case for that how could I do that?

Comment: Suggestion: not have in depth knowledge but isn’t jest **primarily*** used for frontend testing? I mean you can probably use it test your NodeJs endpoints but we used to use Mocha chai. Can help you with that

Comment: You should write test cases for each API and can use  `supertest` to make api call, you can follow this article https://codeforgeek.com/unit-testing-nodejs-application-using-mocha/